# Can you figure out the password?

Tags: word, steganography, password

This past week, I was trying to remember my password for my computer. However, no matter how hard I tried, there was just no way that I could figure it out. Eventually, after several attempts, I gave up and decided to just scourge my desk for any help.

Propitiously, I found a piece of paper on my desk that seemed like it could help. After examining it for several days, I was still unable to decipher the cryptic nature of the message. Soon, I gave up hope on that too and decided to occupy my time with other trivial matters. Sometime later, I was drawn again back to the paper. While I was still confused about its befuddling language, I decided to consult with some friends. Occasionally, some of them would think they had a breakthrough only to be disappointed later. "Rest assured" they would tell me, we'll solve this for you soon enough. Days passed, with still no result coming of our countless hours spent on this puzzle.

I still believe that the gracious people at Puzzle.SE might be able to solve this puzzle. So, after several days of failed attempts by many of my more than capable friends and I, I shall present this puzzle to you - wonderful members here at Puzzle.SE.

Learn from our mistakes, however, don't expect it to be easy. Almost anytime that we thought we were on to something, it turned out to be a red herring. So, please take your time in solving the puzzle, and don't be upset if you are unable to solve it quickly. The puzzle itself may not seem to make sense, but I assure you, I was in my right mind when I made it :

LETTER

1, 2.........swap visa
3, 4.........days months
5, 6.........how to
7, 8.........murder bad

Hint:

> First off, I don't know why I didn't use sentences in the letter. I probably just didn't know how to start them. Right off the bat, you could tell that the letter was pretty ambiguous. So, I'll help you out with some of the things that we found. The LETTER itself is very confusing, but we found that the 8 numbers probably means that there are 8 letters in the password... Maybe you can try rereading the passage again to see if there is anything you missed?

Comment: "Don't spend too much time on the puzzle"..."Please take your time in solving the puzzle..." Is that a deliberate contradiction?

Comment: @F1Krazy edited that lol :P

Comment: You know you've been on this site too long when you can no longer tell whether something's a mistake or an actual part of the puzzle.

Comment: @F1Krazy hahahah

Answer (score 8, accepted):

missed out on the fist right answer by SirGrapeFruit but i will elaborate with an explanation.

The password is

> "Password" (should really look to change that haha)

here is my solution (note: the hint helped alot)

> "I probably just didn't know how to start them" was the first major hint. Looking at the first letter of each sentence you get "THE PASSWORD IS LAST". Then from here, you check the last letter of each word from the letter to get "password"

Answer (score 5):

Well, my idea would be:

> "password".

Reason:

> If you combine the last letter of each word on the right, you get the word "password" (which is literally the [eighth worst password you could think of](https://keepersecurity.com/public/Most-Common-Passwords-of-2016-Keeper-Security-Study.pdf) and you should be ashamed for using it :P).

Comment: You went one step too far ;)

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: tell me how you got it for the tick

Comment: Honestly, I just saw it by accident :P

Comment: Well if you can figure out how to get it, then you can get the check mark :P Until then, you just have a lucky guess, and we don't like lucky guesses >:)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think:

> The total number of characters in "swap visa|days months|how to|murder bad", including spaces but ignoring line breaks (indicated with a |) is exactly equal to 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8. Therefore I took the first letter, then two on etc to end up with 'savdmhud'. Now that is a strong password!

Comment: This is a pretty interesting way that I didn't even see, but it's not the right password sorry :P

Comment: That's okay, I had fun trying this out :)

Comment: :) That's good. Keep trying though, if you can come up with this logic, I'm sure you'll be able to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Proposed Password

> aassoodd, or ssssoodd

Reason

> I assumed that the numbers 1-8 related to the letters in the password, ie 8 letters, also they where paired with a pair of word so I looked for pairs within the words and found that each pair of words had a common unique letter, put it all together and you get aassoodd, or ssssoodd depending on what you do with visa and swap

Comment: The 8 letters part is pretty close, but your answers are not correct, sorry :P